# Sending a phrase (variable) from searcher (from view) to controller, asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create searcher in asp.net. I'm so green about it. I'm trying to create in view and send to controller variable, which has text written in searcher. In that moment, I have smth like that -->
My question is, where and how create and send variable and give her data written in searcher?

Layout

```
form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Searcher", FormMethod.Post, new { phrase = "abc" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Wpisz frazę...">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">@Html.ActionLink("Szukaj", "Index", "Searcher")</button>
            }
        </form>
```

Controller

```
 public class SearcherController : ApplicationController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string message)
    {
        ViewBag.phrase = message;
        getCurrentUser();
        return View();
    }

}
```

View

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
    <li>@ViewBag.message</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You just only need simple submit button inside your @using (Html.BeginForm) without @Html.ActionLink("Szukaj", "Index", "Searcher"). To add "Szukaj" inside your button you have to put it as value parametr of the button, like that <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Szukaj" />.  And you don't need form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search"> because Html.BeginForm insert this tag into your html code.

Comment: And FormMethod.Post isn't correct parametr because your's controller action recives only GET request (because of HttpGet verb). Replace FormMethod.Post with FormMethod.Get and use my previous comment and all will be ok.

Comment: In addition to @ArhiChief, comments, you also need to give the input a `name` attribute so it posts back its value - `<input type="text" name="message" ../>` And remove the `new { phrase = "abc" }` from the `BeginForm()` method (`phrase` is not a valid attribute for a form tag)

Comment: Thank you, it works,I successfully  sent my word! I have a question, because friend down to me tell about it. I need smth like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a key part of MVC -> the **Model**.

Let's create one first:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

Then let's update your "Layout" view (don't know why you had a form in a form?):

```
@model SearchModel

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Searcher", FormMethod.Post, new { phrase = "abc" }))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Criteria)
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">@Html.ActionLink("Szukaj", "Index", "Searcher")</button>
        }
```

Then your action that serves that view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new SearchModel());
}
```

Then your post method would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel model)
{
    ViewBag.phrase = model.Criteria;
    getCurrentUser();
    return View();
}
```